# Ошибка при выполнении метода getMessages в скрипте (google apps script)

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Задача: в гугл-таблице необходимо создать `bound-script`, который из `gmail` подтягивал бы содержание некоторых писем и вставлял бы их в таблицу.
Пока пытаюсь решить вопрос с непосредственно получением сообщений.

```
function getMessageText(){
  var threads = GmailApp.search('from:support@xxxxxx.ru subject:"Ответ на запрос дополнительной информации"', 0, GmailApp.getInboxUnreadCount());
  var messages = threads.getMessages();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow(["Messages unread in inbox: "+ GmailApp.getInboxUnreadCount()]);
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
  sheet.appendRow([threads[i].getFirstMessageSubject()]);
    }
```

Код выше возвращает следующую ошибку

> TypeError: Не удается обнаружить функцию getMessages в объекте

Подскажите причину ошибки. По возможности прошу подробнее описать причины и решение проблемы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по вашему коду, вам не нужны сообщения, а достаточно перебрать цепочки

```
function getMessageText() {

    // Получаем цепочки
    var threads = GmailApp.search('from:google.com is:unread', 0, GmailApp.getInboxUnreadCount());

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.appendRow(["Messages unread in inbox: " + GmailApp.getInboxUnreadCount()]);
    // Logger.log(["Messages unread in inbox: "+ GmailApp.getInboxUnreadCount()]);

    // Перебираем цепочки
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {

        sheet.appendRow([threads[i].getFirstMessageSubject()]);
        // Logger.log([threads[i].getFirstMessageSubject()]);

    }

}
```

Бонус. Вообще не понятно использование `GmailApp.getInboxUnreadCount()`. Если действительно нужны непрочитанные и входящите, то необходимо в каждый запрос добавлять `is:unread is:inbox`

Comment: спасибо за помощь. Из Вашего запроса мы в итоге получим список тем непрочитанных сообщений, верно? А как получить текст самих сообщений?

Comment: @Barmaley, ваш вопрос, в конкретной его фазе (именно код), содержал требования по получению заголовков. Отметьте эту тему как решенную. Создайте новую тему с точным вопросом. Иначе не по правилам форума. В общем случае, вам необходимо ответить еще на ряд вопросов. Во-первых, какие сообщения из цепочек вы собираетесь получать: все, только непрочитанные, помеченные или пр. Во-вторых, уточните строку вашего запроса, вся сила gmail в GCS. В-третьих, генерируя плохо сформулированные вопросы, вы получаете неожиданные ответы. Попробуйте перейти к узкой одноплановой задаче.

Comment: Спасибо. Эту тему пометил решенной, открыл [другую](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/714126/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B8-google-apps-script-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE)