# Сохранение поиска Gmail в Таблицу

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script, gmail

## Дано

- Gmail
- bound-script в Таблице

## Задача

Получить выборку из Gmail в Таблицу Google на основе запроса поиска и требований к самому сообщению. Например, только непрочитанные от конкретного отправителя с конкретной темой сообщения.

Пока удалось получить только количество непрочитанных сообщений и темы необходимых сообщений, используя следующий код [Ошибка при выполнении метода getMessages в скрипте (google apps script)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/713300):

```
function getMessageText() {

    // Получаем цепочки
    var threads = GmailApp.search('from:google.com is:unread', 0, GmailApp.getInboxUnreadCount());

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.appendRow(["Messages unread in inbox: " + GmailApp.getInboxUnreadCount()]);
    // Logger.log(["Messages unread in inbox: "+ GmailApp.getInboxUnreadCount()]);

    // Перебираем цепочки
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {

        sheet.appendRow([threads[i].getFirstMessageSubject()]);
        // Logger.log([threads[i].getFirstMessageSubject()]);

    }

}
```

Каким образом получить тело этих писем?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно скрыть перебор всех сообщений за функцией

```
function messageExtractor_(q, threadCallback, messageCallback, data) {

  threadCallback = getFn_(threadCallback);
  messageCallback = getFn_(messageCallback);

  var threads = GmailApp.search(q);
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var __ = threadCallback(threads[i], i, data);
    if (__ === true) continue;
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
      messageCallback(messages[j], j, data);
    }
  }
  return data;
}
```

Минимальная обертка для колбэка

```
function getFn_(fn) {
    return typeof fn === 'function' ? fn : function() {};
}
```

Теперь можно делать выборки по принципу фильтра. Например, можно пропускать 
 обработку всех сообщений, если в теме цепочки есть слово 'ZDM' `if(/ZDM/.test(th.getFirstMessageSubject())) return true;`, конечно, это можно было сделать и в запросе `'from:google.com is:inbox is:unread -subject:ZDM'`, но тогда бы мы не смогли обработать эти цепочки вообще. Т.е. много всяких приятных вещей получается.

Ок. Добавим обновлялку Таблицы. Обратите внимание у меня это не bound скрипт, но вы можете переделать эту функцию под себя заменив на `ActiveSheet`

```
function setValuesToBase_(values) {
  SpreadsheetApp.openById('XYZ')
    .getSheets()[0]
    .clearContents()
    .getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length)
    .setValues(values);
}
```

Пример использования. Я хочу обновлять первый лист Таблицы с id 'XYZ' на данные следующего характера:

- Сообщения текущего Gmail от google.com, чтобы в теме содержался текст  "#gdocs"
- 4 колонки - тип (трэд или месседж), тема или пусто, пусто или тело, ссылка (только для текущего аккаунта)
- Если тема содержит "ZDM", то добавить в Таблицу только строку с этой темой
- Сообщения добавлять только непрочитанные

_

```
function example() {
  var data = messageExtractor_('from:google.com is:inbox is:unread  subject:#gdocs',
    function(th, i, data) {
      data.push(['Тема', th.getFirstMessageSubject(), '', Utilities.formatString('https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#/%s', th.getId())]);
      if (/ZDM/.test(th.getFirstMessageSubject())) return true;
    },
    function(msg, i, data) {
      if (msg.isUnread())
        data.push(['Сообщение', '', msg.getPlainBody(), Utilities.formatString('https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#/%s', msg.getId())]);
    }, []);

  setValuesToBase_(data);
}
```

Полный пример https://github.com/oshliaer/google-apps-script-snippets/issues/11

Comment: Спасибо большое за подробный разбор с примером. К сожалению, до выходных не будет возможности проверить его работу. Если я помечу Ваш ответ как решение, то могу в дальнейшем здесь задавать Вам вопросы по работе скрипта?

Comment: @Barmaley, конечно. Можете писать сюда https://plus.google.com/communities/103356854721490738172 тоже.